# Number of rows inside date interval, which is taken from dataframe itself (pandas)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name    Date
Alice   2023-01-01
Alice   2023-02-01
Bob     2023-02-15
Alice   2023-03-01
Bob     2023-03-20
Alice   2023-04-01
```

I want to count how many occurences there were for each **Name** in the past 3 months before **Date**. So, I expect to get the following output:

```
    Name    Date        Date_3_Months_Ago   N_Past_3_Months
0   Alice   2023-01-01  2022-10-01          1
1   Alice   2023-02-01  2022-11-01          2
3   Alice   2023-03-01  2022-12-01          3
5   Alice   2023-04-01  2023-01-01          4
2   Bob     2023-02-15  2022-11-15          1
4   Bob     2023-03-20  2022-12-20          2
```

I am able to get this output using apply function or for loop. However, I am interested in vectorized solutions as my dataframe is very large.

Answer (score 1):

I used pandas  Dateoffset to substract 3 months from df['Date'] and groupby with cumcount to count the entry of each name, + 1 because cumcount starts counting from 0

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Date_3_Months_Ago'] = df['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3)
df['N_Past_3_Months'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1
```

end result:

```
    Name    Date        Date_3_Months_Ago   N_Past_3_Months
0   Alice   2023-01-01  2022-10-01          1
1   Alice   2023-02-01  2022-11-01          2
3   Alice   2023-03-01  2022-12-01          3
5   Alice   2023-04-01  2023-01-01          4
2   Bob     2023-02-15  2022-11-15          1
4   Bob     2023-03-20  2022-12-20          2
```

Comment: Does not work if there is a gap in dates. For example, if for 'Alice' you would replace '2023-04-01' by '2023-09-01', the results would not change and return 4 for that row instead of 1.

Comment: You want to count consecutive months for each name?

Comment: I want to count how many occurrences there are for each name in the past 3 months for each row. Does not have to be consecutive. Also, there can be more than one occurrence in the same month.

Answer (score 0):

An approach using a [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and a monthly [`Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html), which should also work if you have missing dates:

```py
N = 3

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Date'], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
period = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')

tmp = (df
   .set_index(period)
   .assign(new=1)
   .groupby('Name')['new']
   .rolling(3+1, min_periods=1).sum()
   .reset_index()
)

df[f'N_Past_{N}_Months'] = df.merge(tmp, left_on=['Name', period],
                                    right_on=['Name', 'Date'])['new']
```

Output:

```
    Name       Date  N_Past_3_Months
0  Alice 2023-01-01              1.0
1  Alice 2023-02-01              2.0
3  Alice 2023-03-01              4.0
5  Alice 2023-04-01              2.0
2    Bob 2023-02-15              3.0
4    Bob 2023-03-20              1.0
```

Comment: Does not work if there is a gap in dates. For example, if for 'Alice' you would replace '2023-04-01' by '2023-09-01', the results would not change and return 4 for that row instead of 1.